# Spring - setting a foreign entity as an attribute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When i have two entities, for example :

```
@Entity
class Table{
   @Id
   Long id;
}


@Entity
class Order{
  @Id
  Long id;

  @OneToOne
  Table tableThisOrderBelongsTo;
}
```

If i want to create an Order, and i have a table id, instead of just placing that table id in Order, i have to use that table id to find that Table, then set that Table inside the order. Even though in the database, Order will look something like { Id: 1, TableId: 1}, i cant just do a

```
Order order = new Order()
order.setId(1);
order.setTableThisOrderBelongsTo(1);
```

I have to do a:

```
Table table = tableRepoisotry.findTableById(1);
order.setTableThisOrderBelongsTo(table);
```

So basicily i am doing an extra query for a table, which is pretty unecesary since i have the table Id already, is there any way to skip doing that query? Should Order look like this:

```
class Order{
@Id
Long id;

Long tableId;
}
```

?
Everything i've read always has the entire object as an attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you are looking for [EntityManager.getReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) method, which is exposed in Spring Data as [JpaRepository.getOne](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-)

I also recommend [How do find and getReference EntityManager methods work when using JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/)